# Standing waves modes inside a cavity resonator

Tags: resonance

[Follow up post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458428/visual-understanding-of-em-fields-within-a-rectangular-metal-container)I have researched the concept of a rectangular cavity resonator and have come across the term modes. For a given frequency one can have multiple modes. What do these multiple modes signify practically? Are some modes better than others?

In addition, when multiple modes do co-exist in a rectangular cavity resonator was does mean. I am not designing a but have got a metal container to which I have fitted an antenna to it. There are multiple modes that co-exist. Is this a bad thing?

Comment: depends on dimension of the cavity vs. frequency

Comment: @MarkoBuršič size is 12.03m by 2.39m by 1.84m (lxbxh) and frequency is 915MHz.

Comment: Note: This looks like a follow up to this user's [earlier question on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502661/visual-understanding-of-em-fields-within-a-rectangular-metal-container). And [this one on EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458428/visual-understanding-of-em-fields-within-a-rectangular-metal-container).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? When you ask if some modes are better, better at what?

Comment: @ThePhoton it is, but is seemed to me that is a different topic to the question I have asked in that post. Hence I thought it deserved its own post. Should I remove this post and continue it on my previous post?

Comment: I think it's fair to ask as a new question, but you should link the old questions so that people know the context of why you're asking.

Comment: However I do think the answers and comments you got before also answer this question. The consequences are you won't be able to predict the behavior very well at all (this is stated in Neil's answer and  user24368's comments on the previous EE question).

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you, firstly I dont know how to do that, could you edit my post? Secondly there isnt any problem in particular. I just want to get insight on the reason why people go onto to calculate different modes. Hence are they trying to find which is better in terms of the performance of the resonator and why is it better. My cavity resonator is backwards in terms of I am not designing one but I already one and hence I  would like to simulate the behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98644/discussion-between-joey-and-the-photon).